# Stop a timer in an OSGI bundle

Tags: java, timer, osgi, osgi-bundle

So , i have an OSGi bundle  which creates a timer like this...

```
       Timer timer = new Timer(true);
       // running timer task as daemon thread
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 2 * 1000);//my class extends the timer task 
       // cancel after 60s
        try 
        {
           Thread.sleep(60000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
           timer.cancel();
        }
```

This works fine as long the OSGi bundle is not stopped before the timer task ends. If i try to stop the bundle before the timer timeout(i.e 60 s) , i get an exception that the bundle could not be stopped cleanly.

On my bundle's deactivate method , i cancel the timer but i guess since the thread is sleeping the bundle's stop doesn't get called before the time out

I just wanted to understand if there is a way i can stop the bundle before the timeout which will kill the timer task  as well ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) to cancel threads. OSGi isn't any different than other applications when it comes to concurrency.

The code you posted should run in its own separate thread and you need to keep a reference to that thread. When the bundle is deactivated, send an interrupt to that thread using [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29).Your code would actually work already, but probably don't want to print the stack trace though. Here is an example:

```
cancelTimerThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.debug("timer canceled by bundle stop");
        }
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
cancelTimerThread.start();
```

On bundle deactivation:

```
public void stop() {
    // signal thread to cancel timer early
    cancelTimerThread.interrupt();
}
```

Beware that when using `timer.cancel()`, the current running timer task wont be aborted. If it were a long running task, you should probably send an interrupt to that task too.

Comment: but shouldn't the thread.sleep() throw an InterruptedException when the bundle is stopped ?...i changed the code to cancel the timer in the catch block of interruptedexception but i still get the same error ..."bundle cannot be stopped cleanly"

Comment: @user2912902 It should, if you call `interrupt()`, but it won't happen automatically. `cancel` still needs to be called after the try/catch, not just inside the catch block - in case the sleep ends without interrupt.